# Assign Domain Name For Same IP, Different Nodeports Minikube

Tags: service, devops, kubernetes-ingress, minikube, domain-name

I'm trying to set up a local environment for microservices using minikube. My cluster consists of 4 pods and the minikube ip for all 4 of them are the same. However, each service runs on a unique nodeport.
EG: 172.42.159.12:12345 & 172.42.159.12:23456

Ingress generates them as

- http://172.42.159.12:12345
- http://172.42.159.12:23456
- http://172.42.159.12:34567
- http://172.42.159.12:45678

They all work fine when using the ip to access them, and they work fine when using a loadbalancer and deploying a cloud environment.
But I want this to work on my minikube, and I can't use the ../etc/hosts to assign domain names for each service ecause it does not accept the nodeports being passed in.

Any help on this is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

so I found a solution for this.
The only way to do it is with a third-party app called [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler).

How To:

- Download And Run Fiddler
- Open Fiddler => Rules => Customize Rules
- Scroll down to find `static function OnBeforeRequest(oSession: Session)`
- Pass in

```js
        if (oSession.HostnameIs("your-domain.com")){
            oSession.bypassGateway = true;
            oSession["x-overrideHost"] = "minikube_ip:your_port";
        }
```

- Save File